# However you parse the data from the email

Tags: c#, email, azure-functions, power-automate, data-extraction

I am very desperate, I need to get data from each new email, which will be saved to a file on my PC, where I will work with it in C#. I really don't know how to get the data. Power Automate was recommended to me, but I don't know how to use it. The only thing I can come up with so far is [image: this the text is split up]

but I need to save them to a file.Or is there not some simple or better way to do this? Please help, I really don't know how to go on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install the EAGetMail package from NuGet

```
Install-Package EAGetMail
```

EAGetMail is a POP3 and IMAP4 component which supports all operations of POP3/IMAP4/MIME/Exchange Web.

You can find all the information that you need here:
https://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=0

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can save the generated data to your Azure blob in your required format, and then using the Azure functions' timer trigger or blob trigger you can save all the azure blobs locally to your PC.

Consider below is the workflow.
[image]

Below is my Azure Blob trigger

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp5
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task RunAsync([BlobTrigger("container1/{name}", Connection = "ConStr")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
            BlobClient blobClient=new BlobClient("<ConnectionString>", "Container1",name);
            await blobClient.DownloadToAsync("<Local Path>");
        }
    }
}
```

**RESULTS:**
In my Storage Account

[image]

In my local pc

[image]